# Do the following two derivations imply each other?

Tags: logic

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/ says

> A proposition is a subaltern of another iff it must be true if its superaltern is true, and the superaltern must be false if the subaltern is false.

Do the following two derivations imply each other?

- if proposition P is true, then proposition Q is true
- if proposition Q is false, then proposition P is false

Can the quote be simplified to:

> A proposition is a subaltern of another iff it must be true if its superaltern is true.

or

> A proposition is a subaltern of another iff the superaltern must be false if the subaltern is false.

Is the subalternation relationship between superaltern and subaltern a derivational one between two propositions, or implicational one between component propositions in a compound proposition? (I guess the former.)

Comment: Yes; see [Square of Opposition](https://iep.utm.edu/sqr-opp/): "two propositions are said to stand in the relation of *subalternation* when the truth of the first (“the superaltern”) implies the truth of the second (“the subaltern”), but not conversely. An **A** propositions stand in the subalternation relation with the corresponding **I** propositions. The truth of the proposition “all plastics are synthetic,” implies the truth of the proposition “some plastics are synthetic.”  1/2

Comment: In traditional logic, the truth of an A or E proposition implies the truth of the corresponding I or O proposition, respectively. *Consequently, the falsity of an I or O proposition implies the falsity of the corresponding A or E proposition, respectively*. [...] The presupposition, mentioned above, that all categories contain at least one thing, has been abandoned by most later logicians." 2/2

Comment: Is the subalternation relationship between superaltern and subaltern a derivational one between two propositions, or implicational one between component propositions in a compound proposition?

Comment: The question: "Do the following two derivations imply each other?..." needs [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition_(traditional_logic)) because in traditional logic and modern classical one "Q is false" iff "not-Q is true".

Comment: In A's syllogism "**A** is true" implies "**I** is true" but in modern logic **∀x(Sx→Px) ⊭ ∃x(Sx&Px)**

Answer (score 2):

Mauro's answer is complete and authoritative, and Wikipedia's article on [subalternation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subalternation) is technical, but illuminating. Let's start with an example in natural language:

> An example of a subalternation is "If all squares are quadrilaterals, then some quadrilaterals are squares."

[image: From WP article Square of Opposition]

All we've done is drawn a more particular conclusion from the original proposition. What is important is that the truth follows from [form or syntax, not content or semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax%E2%80%93semantics_interface). Thus, it is of the form:

> ∀s Qs ⊨ ∃s Qs

Where "∀s" means "all squares", "∃s" means "there exists some squares", and "Qs" means "squares are quadrilaterals". The symbol "⊨" can be read as "always entails" and means that there are no exceptions to the rule. Put together: **All squares are quadrilaterals always entails some squares are quadrilaterals.** In terms of the Venn diagram, this means that if all members of one circle are in another circle, some portion of those members must be in the circle.

Ultimately, it's one type of relationship that can be found to inhere to the [square of opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition). You ask:

> Is the subalternation relationship between superaltern and subaltern a derivational one between two propositions, or implicational one between component propositions in a compound proposition?

Thus, the superaltern always **implies** the subaltern, but not vice versa. If a conclusion and antecedent imply each other, then the implication is a [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) and is qualified as biconditional. For instance:

> "Some quadrilaterals are squares does not imply all quadrilaterals are squares" is true.

Indeed, kites are not. The biconditional is thus false.

> "Some quadrilaterals are squares implies all quadrilaterals are squares" is false.

[Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) is a type of [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence), and a derivation in the language of logic is a proof. From the article on [formal proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof):

> In logic and mathematics, a formal proof or derivation is a finite sequence of sentences (called well-formed formulas in the case of a formal language), each of which is an axiom, an assumption, or follows from the preceding sentences in the sequence by a rule of inference. It differs from a natural language argument in that it is rigorous, unambiguous and mechanically verifiable.

Comment: "*All squares are quadrilaterals ***always entails*** some squares are quadrilaterals.*" Always entails? Could you give an example where p does entail q but not always?

Comment: @Speakpigeon Okay, let's keep it simple. Consider where p does not always entail q. Some bachelors are men but not all men are bachelors. Thus P->Q does not imply Q->P. In this case Some Q->P can be read "Q partially entails P". That is absolutely part of the square of opposition in a subaltern. All bachelors are men implies some bachelors are men. That is ALWAYS entailed. But being a man POSSIBLY or PARTIALLY or CONTINGENTLY entails being a bachelor contingent upon the man in question.

Comment: The moral of the story is that the square of opposition and simple classical logics are formal systems constructed that model some states of affairs in the physical world and not others, and we can always vary the linguistic artifact to have more complex systems of logical consequence.

Comment: @speakpigeon Okay, while I deleted my earlier portion, it's still probably important to point you to the difference between [proof-theoretic and model-theoretic logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Proofs_and_models). Besides contingent implication there is also implication across contexts or models. Thus, sometimes P->Q is true in System A and sometimes the same P->Q is false but in System B. Here again, P doesn't ALWAYS entail Q. "I am happy" is true for me, but it may not be for my opponent in the Fornite battle royale (zero sum win!)

Comment: So, those are the proof-theoretic (single turnstile) and model-theoretic (double turnstile) examples of contingent implication.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with saying "material implication is a type of logical consequence". Material implication is a connective within the object language, while logical consequence is a relation within the metalanguage. In classical logic there is a simple relation between the two, because of the way the introduction and elimination rules work. But it is not a case of one being a type of the other.

Comment: @Bumble Mere discomfort is generous. As skipper, I must own that the ship is not merely listing, but has capsized. I've righted the ship by replacing "consequence" with "connective". That being said, there's a certain if-thenishness about both material implication and logical consequence that transcends the object-metalanguage divide. Would it be acceptable to characterize both as species of "logical necessity"? Does that taxonomical assertion pass muster?

Comment: I wouldn't describe material implication as a relation of necessity. It says merely that if the antecedent is true, the consequent is true. There is no built-in modal flavour. Strict implication is material implication within the scope of a box operator.

Comment: Okay. Twice now,  you demonstrate my terminology is using a non-technical sense incommensurate. So, is there a hypernym to encompass an extension that includes condional connectives, logical consequence,  logical necessity,  metaphysical necessity,  and others? They appear to be concepts in an object language that are specific species resulting from conditional connectives in a metaphysical metalanguage of sorts  that might presume they all result from a reduction to a type of deterministic neural computation.  Do you logic boffins have a lexical definiens? Or is this non- canonical thought?

Comment: @Bumble Oops forgot tag.

Comment: For myself, I would be content to say that all of these are kinds of *conditionals*. Material implication is a kind of conditional, as are statements of conditional probability, strict implications, conditionals within non-classical logics, etc. A logical consequence relation could be thought of as a strict conditional in which the modality is one of logical necessity. That said, there are many different theories of what conditionals are. Many theorists hold a version of inferentialism under which conditionals are nothing more than implication relations, but I think that is rather too narrow.

Comment: @Bumble Thanks a heap! 'Conditionals' is exactly what they're called in a Turing machine so no stretch at all from my metaphysical prejudices. :D